# Golang app using sync.WaitGroup & channels never exits

Tags: go, goroutine

I use `sync.WaitGroup`, `defer wg.Close()` and `wg.Wait()` to wait for my goroutines to complete.

The program do wait, but it never exits.

This is my program (runnable):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

var symbols = []string{
    "ASSA-B.ST",
    "ELUX-B.ST",
    "HM-B.ST",
}

func main() {

    fmt.Println("fetching quotes...")

    fetchedSymbols := make(chan string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(symbols))

    for _, symbol := range symbols {
        go fetchSymbol(symbol, &wg, fetchedSymbols)
    }

    for response := range fetchedSymbols {
        fmt.Println("fetched " + response)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("done")

}

func fetchSymbol(symbol string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, c chan<- string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    resp, err := http.Get("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + symbol + "&a=0&b=1&c=2000")
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    out, err := os.Create("./stock-quotes/" + symbol + ".csv")
    defer out.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
    c <- symbol
}
```

Shouldn't this program exit when all the quotes have been downloaded? (FYI: I just started learning GO)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're never closing the `fetchedSymbols` channel, so that range loop will never exit.

One way to handle this is to use use the WaitGroup you already have to signal when to close the channel. Ranging over `fetchedSymbols` is enough to block the progress in main, and you don't need another channel or WaitGroup.

```
...
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(fetchedSymbols)
}()

for response := range fetchedSymbols {
    fmt.Println("fetched " + response)
}

...
```